# Не работает обьявление шаблона класса в заголовочном файле с определением методов в отдельном файле реализации

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Например у меня есть `Test.h` в котором определен шаблон класса `Test` и в `Test.cpp` определены методы и конструкторы класса причем неявным образом,а вот уже где нибудь в `main.cpp` я инициализирую `Test<int> testValue`. Ничего не сработает, так как компилятор не знает, как определить мои `Type` в `Test.cpp`. Как можно "схитрить" ( Не используя дополнительного третьего файла типа `.inl` или что нибудь еще)

**Test.h**

```
#ifndef Test
#define Test

template <class Type>
class Test
{
private:
    Type value;
public:
    Test(Type valueOfUser);
    Type getValue();
};

#endif // Test
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"

template <typename Type> Test<Type>::Test(Type valueOfUser): value(valueOfUser) {}
template <typename Type> Type Test<Type>::getValue () { return value; }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"

intt main()
{
  Test<int> test;
  test.getValue();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1798717.html#post9488987

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть один способ, но неудобный.

В `test.cpp` можно *явно инстанцировать* `class Test` для `Type = int`, добавив в конец файла:

```
template class Test<int>;
```

Неудобство в том, что в `.cpp` файле вы должны перечислить все наборы шаблонных аргументов, с которыми планируете использовать класс.

Это - самое последнее средство. Намного лучше будет послушать @Harry и просто держать дефиниции шаблонных функций в заголовочных файлах.

Comment: А  почему `template` без `<>` , просто я знаю, что можно писать `template <>` в определенных случаях, а вот без `<>` ? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Kaznachei С `<>` пишется [явная (полная) специализация](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), а тут - [явное инстанцирование](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Class_template_instantiation).

Comment: А что значит дефиниция шаблонных функции, а то в гугле про социологию что-то выдает?

Comment: @Kaznachei "Дефиниция" значит "определение". Например, `void f();` - объявление функции, а `void f() {}` - определение.

Answer (score 13):

Уж сколько раз твердили миру... (с)

Не помещайте определения шаблонных функций/классов в отдельные .cpp-файлы. Размещайте все только в заголовочных файлах - иначе инстанцирования не происходит, вот и имеем, что имеем.

Совет от Страуструпа (A Tour of C++, adv. 7-6):

> Раздельной компиляции шаблонов нет: вы должны включать с помощью директивы #include определения шаблонов в каждую единицу трансляции, которая их использует.

Вот подумайте сами - откуда при компиляции файла Test.cpp компилятору знать, что (с каким параметром шаблона) будет инстанцироваться в другом файле?

А в этом другом файле (main.cpp) - откуда знать, как инстанцировать шаблон, если нет доступа к коду реализации?

Обходной путь - указать в файле реализации шаблона явное инстанцирование необходимых типов

```
template class Test<конкретный_тип>;
```

возможен, но очень уж он неудобный - в следующий раз в `main.cpp` понадобится  класс для нового типа, и надо будет тут же вносить его в `test.cpp`. Еще хуже, если какой-то тип станет ненужен, но будет продолжать инстанцироваться и линковаться.

Comment: А как быть с множественным определением ? Или `#ifndef` `#define` меня спасет ?

Comment: @Kaznachei Спасет. Шаблонные функции - всегда автоматически `inline`. С `inline` ведь не возникает такой проблемы.

Comment: Для шаблонов это вопрос отдельный - у них свои правила. Со ссылками на стандарт и прочими умными терминами - это уж пусть гуру расскажут...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Формально шаблонные функции не являются "автоматически inline", но в рамках ODR эффект действительно как от `inline`.

Comment: А что, если у меня много раз подключится `Test.h` например в `main.cpp` и будет куча продублированного кода, хотя он не будет выполняться , это скажется на размере исполняемого файла , или любого другого ?

Comment: @AnT Хм. Понял, запомню.

Comment: @AnT А если у меня шаблонная функция длинная или с каким нибудь циклом, она все равно будет как `inline` ? Компилятор может же не вставить функцию в код которая была определена как `inline` , а внутри этой функции какой нибудь "зверский" цикл

Comment: @Kaznachei: Если ваш `Test.h` много раз включится в `main.cpp`, то будет ошибка компиляции. Но такого быть не может - у вас include guards специально для этого стоят.

Comment: @Kaznachei: `inline` уже давно [почти] не влияет на встраивание или невстраивание функции. Поэтому не ясно, о чем вы спрашиваете. Какая разница, есть там "зверский цикл" или нет?

Comment: @AnT Например у меня будет еще один заголовочный файл `Test1.h` к которому подключаю `Test.h` и в `main.cpp` я подключаю `Test1.h` и `Test.h`

Comment: @AnT Ну, видимо, да. Просто я знаю только что `inline` встраивает и дает возможность инициализировать статическую переменную внутри класса.

Comment: @Kaznachei: И? Еще раз: ваши include guards предотвратят двойное включение `Test.h` в `main.cpp`. Для того они и поставлены.

Comment: @AnT Я в плане, у меня в `main.cpp` два одинаковых кода , но которые охвачены в `header guards`. Повлияет ли это на размер моего исполняемого файла или на какой нибудь из стадии (препроцессинг, ассемблирование, компиляция) вырежется код и останется только один, то есть не будет продублированного кода и это не повлияет на размер исполняемого файла

Comment: @Kaznachei Конечно не повлияет, ведь include guard'ы уберут все повторные включения этого кода (на стадии препроцессинга).

Comment: @Kaznachei Вы бы выбрали какой-то из ответов как принятый, чтоб ваш вопрос можно было использовать как образец - указывать в качестве уже решенного для дублей...

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, неработоспособность вашего подхода никак не связана с тем, что "компилятор не знает, как определить мои Type в Test.cpp". Вы продолжаете это повторять из вопроса в вопрос, но никакого отношения к сути проблемы это не имеет.

Во-вторых, возможность силой "заставить" что-то работать в таком варианте у вас есть: через явное инстанцирование ваших определений в `.cpp` файле для тех типов, с которыми ваш шаблон используется в программе. Но это в общем случае является нецелевым использованием возможности явного инстанцирования.

Вся суть шаблонов заключается в том, что компилятор должен сам *автоматически* определять, какие версии ваших шаблонных сущностей нужны в программе и генерировать их *автоматически*. Для этого нужно, чтобы все определения шаблонов выли видны *везде*, а не прятались в каком-то `.cpp` файле. Возможность явного инстанцирования существует в языке в первую очередь для оптимизации этого процесса, а не для того, чтобы заменять автоматическое инстанцирование на ручное.