# Компиляция в Eclipse C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, компиляция

подскажите как Вы компилируете в Eclipse?

Я начал писать один проект, и столкнулся со следующем (ниже прикладываю код)

Property.h

```
#ifndef PROPERTY
#define PROPERTY

#include <stdlib.h>
#include<functional>

using namespace std;

namespace Extentions
{
// Property types
class ReadOnly;
class WriteOnly;
class ReadWrite;

// Property structure
template<typename T_param, typename Access>
class Property;

// Property getter
    template<typename T_param>
    class Property<T_param, ReadOnly>
    {
    protected:
        T_param *_param;
    public:
        Property(T_param *param) : _param(param){};

        operator T_param();
    };

    template<typename T_param>
    Property<T_param, ReadOnly>::operator T_param()
    {
        return *_param;
    }

// Property setter
    template<typename T_param>
    class Property<T_param, WriteOnly>
    {
    protected:
        T_param *_param;
        function<bool(T_param)> checkParam;

    public:
        Property(T_param *param, function<bool(T_param)> paramChecker) : _param(param),
        checkParam(paramChecker){};

        void operator =(T_param param);
    };

    template<typename T_param>
    void Property<T_param, WriteOnly>::operator =(T_param param)
    {
        if(checkParam(param))
            *_param = param;
    };

// Property setter and getter
    template<typename T_param>
    class Property<T_param, ReadWrite>
    {
    protected:
        T_param *_param;
        function<bool(T_param)> checkParam;
    public:
        Property(T_param *param, function<bool(T_param)> paramChecker) : _param(param),
        checkParam(paramChecker){};
        Property(T_param *param) : _param(param),
                checkParam([](T_param){ return true;}){};
        void operator =(T_param param);
        operator T_param();
    };

    template<typename T_param>
    void Property<T_param, ReadWrite>::operator =(T_param param)
    {
        if(checkParam(param))
            *_param = param;
    };
    template<typename T_param>
    Property<T_param, ReadWrite>::operator T_param()
    {
        return *_param;
    }
}

#endif
```

Это мой заголовочный файл. А ниже тестовый проект:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../headders/Property.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Extentions;

class MyTestClass
{
private:
    int i = 5;
public:
    Property<int, ReadOnly> p_R;
    Property<int, WriteOnly>p_W;
    Property<int, ReadWrite> p_RW;

    MyTestClass() : p_R(&i),
                    p_W(&i,[](int data){return data > 10;}),
                    p_RW(&i){}

};

int main() {

    MyTestClass cl;

    cl.p_RW = 18;
    int j = cl.p_RW;

    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Когда я компилирую все как есть сейчас - все компилируется, однако когда я пробую выносить реализацию методов в Property.cpp (т.е. просто переношу реализацию которая сейчас в заголовочном файле объявлена - в файл с расширением .cpp) - я получаю ошибку. Причем ecleapse прописывает на сколько я понял в make файле все как нужно, ошибка в том что он пытается скомпилировать с явно определенным шаблоном где T_param = int. т.е. если я переношу всю реализацию как есть сейчас из заголовочного файла - в файл 
"Prorerty.cpp" - сыпятся ошибка, но если я в том же Property.cpp не изменяя кода явно реализую шаблон T_param чисто для int то тогда код компилируется и выполняется верно.

Соответственно вопрос, как Вы комплируете код в ecleapse ? Пишите ли Вы собственный make файлы или же доверяете автогенерации ? Я новичок в программировании под линуксом, и по этому сейчас пока хотел бы доверить создание make файла среде разработке, тем более мне нужно будет в дальнейшем дебагить проект в ecleapse и хотелось бы что бы среда сама компилировала все как ей требуется.

**Подскажите как бы разрешить данную ситуацию ?**

**А так же интересует (как дополнение к вопросу) можно ли самому компилировать по собственным make файлам внутри среды (т.е. если я все же захочу скормить Ecleapse свой MakeFile то как мне это сделать ?)**

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1798717.html#post9488987

Comment: @Croessmah Очень полезная ссылка, благодарю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937440/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be

Answer (score 1):

Шаблоны порождают код только тогда, когда вы употребляете этот шаблон в программе с конкретными параметрами. Нельзя скомпилировать модуль содержащий просто шаблон класса. А вот если вам заранее известно, что будет использоваться конкретный тип, можете вынести его в Property.cpp(что вы собственно и сделали для int). Но тогда все что угодно кроме int будет приводить к ошибкам, так что смысла в данном случае так делать не вижу.

Теперь про eclipse(как вы если превратили в ecleapse ума не приложу :D), просто загуглите "creating your makefile eclipse" и получите иллюстрированную статейку на help.eclipce

Comment: Благодарю, оставлю в хедре тогда.