# Ошибка преобразования list<int> в int при реализации односвязного списка

Tags: c++, list, перегрузка-операторов, преобразование

Возникает ошибка при попытке вывести результат: "Не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "List" в "int"" при вызове перегруженного оператора [] для самопального односвязного списка.
Тело списка:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    class List
    {
    private:
        template <typename T>
        class Node
        {
        public:
            T data;
            Node<T>* next;
            Node(T data, Node *next = nullptr) {
                this->data = data;
                this->next = next;
            }
        };
        Node<T>* _first;
        int _countItems;
    public:
        List();
        ~List();
        T& operator[](const int indx);
        void Add(T item);
        void AddAt(T item, int indx);
        void RemoveAt(int indx);
        void Clear();
        int Lenght();
        void Exeption();
    };
```

Тело мейна:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    List<int>* li = new List<int>();
    li->Add(25);
    li->Add(34);
    li->Add(11);
    for (int i = 0; i < li->Lenght(); i++)
    {
        int a = li[i]; //Вот тут ошибка и возникает
        cout << a << "\n";
    }
}
```

Перегрузка оператора: в List.cpp

```cpp
template <typename T>
T& List<T>::operator[](const int indx) {
    Node<T>* current = _first;
    for (int i = 0; i < indx; i++)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    return current->data;
}
```

не могу понять где косяк тут.

Comment: так у вас же не лист а указатель на него. `(*li)[]` попробуйте или что-то такое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас 2 ошибки.

Первая: что такое `li`? **Указатель**:

```
List<int>* li = new List<int>();
```

Значит, что такое `li[i]`? i-й элемент массива, на который указывает `li`. То, что вы хотите - это надо записывать так

```
(*li)[i]
```

или так

```
li->operator[](i)
```

(Или `li[0][i]` :))

А вот вторая выскочит на линковке - потому что реализацию шаблонов в отдельные .cpp [помещать нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937440/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE)...

Comment: да что уж там мелочится с `li[0][i]` надо сразу красиво писать `0[li][i]` :D